# Repository Pattern basic?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can someone explain to me what these statements mean in C#?:

```
class RepositoryBase : IDisposable, IRepositoryBase where TEntity : class{}

class DbContextFactory : IContextFactory where TContext : DbContext, new()
```

I understood that `RepositoryBase` inherits from `IDisposable` and `IRepositoryBase` class. What do the stuff after it mean?

Comment: Isn't it rather `RepositoryBase<TEntity>` ?

Comment: Did you miss out something? possible RepositoryBase<TEntity> rather than RepositoryBase?

Comment: These are type constraints. You can read [the documentation for them at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Comment: By the way, you didn't understand well what you think you understood. Repository base implements IDisposable and IRepositoryBase, which are interfaces, not classes. It's not inheritance.

Comment: @user3488904 where did you get those class definitions from? I'm having trouble finding an exact match for them through Google and MSDN.

Comment: I have got from this link http://www.kenl.net/site/archives/290

Comment: @user3488904 fyi, the latest version of Entity Framework is version 6. Why are you reading a post about version 4? It's 2 years old.

Comment: Actually i am trying to understand the Unit of Work and Repository Pattern. In learning of that i picked up that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Type Constraints

These are all examples of type constraints. You can read more about them from [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

> `where T : class`: The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.
>
> `where T : new()`: The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. When used together with other constraints, the **new()** constraint must be specified last.
>
> `where T : <base class name>`: The type argument must be or derive from the specified base class.

So in your case:

```
class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : /* etc */ where TEntity : class{}
```

means that the `TEntity` in `RepositoryBase<TEntity>` must be a reference type, i.e. an object.

For the second case:

```
class DbContextFactory<TContext> : /* etc */ where TContext : DbContext, new()
```

means that `TContext` must be an instance of `DbContext`, and that `TContext` must have a public constructor of the form

```
public TContext() { /* etc */ }
```

#### Interfaces

Original poster said:

> I understood that `RepositoryBase` inherits from `IDisposable` and `IRepositoryBase` class. What do the stuff after it mean?

The declaration

```
class RepositoryBase : IDisposable, IRepositoryBase
```

means that `RepositoryBase` ***implements*** the `IDisposable` and `IRepositoryBase` ***interfaces***. The `RepositoryBase` ***does not inherit from them***, because they are not classes that can be "inherited" from (in the C# sense).

Instead, `IDisposable` and `IRepositoryBase` are both ***interfaces***, which only specify behavior and methods as a contract, but do not specify implementation. In C#, it is a convention to name all interfaces starting with a capital `I` prefix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer  You are saying i can even write like this  "where T : Array"

Comment: If you want to force `T` to be an instance of type `Array`, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you mean

```
public class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IDisposable, IRepositoryBase where TEntity : class{}
```

?

Then it'd just mean that `TEntity` generic type is supposed o be a class, that's all.

Answer (score -1):

RepositoryBase implements the interface IDisposable and IRepositoryBase